# How to close webkit_server in capybara-webkit when running inside Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, session, capybara, sidekiq, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to run each session of capybara-webkit inside of Sidekiq workers.

For each worker I create a session like this `s = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit)`

After the work is done, I close the session by calling `s.driver.browser.reset!`

But the number of `webkit_server` process keeps increasing, it looks like the process is never been released after the Sidekiq worker is finished.

How can I make sure the `webkit_server` process is closed properly? Is there a way that I can manually close the server?

I'm using capybara-webkit-1.1.1 with Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could figure an (ugly and dirty) workaround, but well, the webkit_servers are going to die now.

```
pid = capybara_ag.driver.inspect.scan(/@pid=(\d+)/).flatten.first
`kill -9 #{pid}`
```

Or you may restart your app.